# Prevent the view being zoomed in or out too far Viewbox pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

Need a way to prevent the view being zoomed in or out too far in viewbox on pyqtgraph.

I referred the current documentation at: http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/viewbox.html

it says there is supposed to be a method to handle such scenario: setLimits

But when I referred the code, this method is not present there.

Need input on if it can be done with existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewBox.setLimits has not been released yet--it is only in the "develop" branch on github. It will be in the 0.9.9 release.

Comment: Any idea when that will be released?